# node mongoose findoneandremove

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

I have a select box with a delete button under it to delete selected value.

del_emp.pug

```
form(action=' ' method='POST')
                    select(name='name')
                        for emp in data
                            option(value= emp) #{emp.name} 
                    br
                    button(type="submit" class="btn btn-default") Submit
```

This router populates the box (works)

```
router.get('/del' , function( req , res){
        Employee.find({ } , 'name -_id' ,function (err,docs){
        res.render('./del_emp.pug' , { data : docs})
        })
})
```

this handles the form POST

```
router.post('/del' , function (req , res){
    Employee.findOneAndRemove( { name : req.body.name } , function(err , msg){
        if (err) {res.send('error')}
        {
            res.send("Deleted" + req.body.name)
        }
    })
} 
)
```

My employee object looks like this

```
var EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
    name : {type: String, required: true},
    dept : { type: String, required: true },
    leaves: {type: Number, required: true},
    manager: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

On submit I get the message Deleted{"name":"dan"}.But the data is still there in the db.What should i change?

Comment: I guess you want to delete `{ name : 'dan' }` and not `{ name : {name:'dan'} }`, right?

Comment: yes,i want to delete that instance ( employee dan)

Comment: Then you have to update your query `{ name : req.body.name }` accordingly because it does not match anything.

Comment: any idea how i can do this ? the list box populates only "dan" using emp.name then why does the req.body.name return { "name" : "dan" } and not only dan?

Comment: Either use `{ name : req.body.name.name }` or change your form.

Comment: This works!Thanks